# Difficulty installing php 5.6.23 using PHPBrew (Error: bz2 module requires libbz2 >= 1.0.0)

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, phpbrew

I am an absolute beginner of Web Development.

**[What I would like to do]**

Install PHP 5.6.23 using PHPBrew

Update the version of **libbz2** package(?)

**[Environment]**

Amazon linux Server(EC2 Instance)

PHPbrew version - 1.22.6

**[Issue]**

When I try to install PHP 5.6.23 by a command below, the error `configure: error: bz2 module requires libbz2 >= 1.0.0` comes out.

I have no idea how to upgrade the version of **libbz2**

`phpbrew install 5.6.23 +default +mysql +openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)`

**.phpbrew/build/php-5.6.23/build.log**

```
checking for PCRE library to use... bundled
checking whether to enable the SQLite3 extension... no
checking for ZLIB support... yes
checking if the location of ZLIB install directory is defined... no
checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.2.8
checking for gzgets in -lz... yes
checking whether to enable bc style precision math functions... yes
checking for BZip2 support... yes
checking for BZ2_bzerror in -lbz2... no
configure: error: bz2 module requires libbz2 >= 1.0.0
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

If you need more information, please leave your comments.
Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need the headers files for compiling, not the binaries. So, please install:

Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

Fedora:

```
$ sudo dnf install bzip2-devel
```